# HTC and Win XP mystery

Tags: windows

At work I use windows xp and every time I connect my HTC One for charging, I get messages that prompt me to download HTC Sync. I can't  stop these disruptive messages and there's no other way to charge my phone. Any ideas?

Comment: You get this on the PC side?  It's probably due to AutoPlay which you can turn off in Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, how do I do that? I can't find AutoPlay in the Control Panel

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. Any ideas?